# Вертикальное меню на сайте

Tags: javascript, меню

Здравствуйте, у меня проблема. Есть меню на главной страннице (сворачивающееся\разворачивающееся). Отображается нормально, но когда переходишь на другую странницу оно должно быть развернутым, но оно свернуто, перелопатил весь JS, перепробовал кучу методов, и не помогло. Уже реально сижу в потерях. Помогите пожалуйста решить эту проблему. [Вот код.](http://goo.gl/dGlTza)

```js
(function ($) {
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $.session = {

            _id: null,

            _cookieCache: undefined,

            _init: function () {
                if (!window.name) {
                    window.name = Math.random();
                }
                this._id = window.name;
                this._initCache();

                // See if we've changed protcols

                var matches = (new RegExp(this._generatePrefix() + "=([^;]+);")).exec(document.cookie);
                if (matches && document.location.protocol !== matches[1]) {
                    this._clearSession();
                    for (var key in this._cookieCache) {
                        try {
                            window.sessionStorage.setItem(key, this._cookieCache[key]);
                        } catch (e) {};
                    }
                }

                document.cookie = this._generatePrefix() + "=" + document.location.protocol + ';path=/;expires=' + (new Date((new Date).getTime() + 120000)).toUTCString();

            },

            _generatePrefix: function () {
                return '__session:' + this._id + ':';
            },

            _initCache: function () {
                var cookies = document.cookie.split(';');
                this._cookieCache = {};
                for (var i in cookies) {
                    var kv = cookies[i].split('=');
                    if ((new RegExp(this._generatePrefix() + '.+')).test(kv[0]) && kv[1]) {
                        this._cookieCache[kv[0].split(':', 3)[2]] = kv[1];
                    }
                }
            },

            _setFallback: function (key, value, onceOnly) {
                var cookie = this._generatePrefix() + key + "=" + value + "; path=/";
                if (onceOnly) {
                    cookie += "; expires=" + (new Date(Date.now() + 120000)).toUTCString();
                }
                document.cookie = cookie;
                this._cookieCache[key] = value;
                return this;
            },

            _getFallback: function (key) {
                if (!this._cookieCache) {
                    this._initCache();
                }
                return this._cookieCache[key];
            },

            _clearFallback: function () {
                for (var i in this._cookieCache) {
                    document.cookie = this._generatePrefix() + i + '=; path=/; expires=Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:01 GMT;';
                }
                this._cookieCache = {};
            },

            _deleteFallback: function (key) {
                document.cookie = this._generatePrefix() + key + '=; path=/; expires=Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:01 GMT;';
                delete this._cookieCache[key];
            },

            get: function (key) {
                return window.sessionStorage.getItem(key) || this._getFallback(key);
            },

            set: function (key, value, onceOnly) {
                try {
                    window.sessionStorage.setItem(key, value);
                } catch (e) {}
                this._setFallback(key, value, onceOnly || false);
                return this;
            },

                'delete': function (key) {
                return this.remove(key);
            },

            remove: function (key) {
                try {
                    window.sessionStorage.removeItem(key);
                } catch (e) {};
                this._deleteFallback(key);
                return this;
            },

            _clearSession: function () {
                try {
                    window.sessionStorage.clear();
                } catch (e) {
                    for (var i in window.sessionStorage) {
                        window.sessionStorage.removeItem(i);
                    }
                }
            },

            clear: function () {
                this._clearSession();
                this._clearFallback();
                return this;
            }

        };

        $.session._init();
        var search = window.location.search.substr(1),
            keys = {};

        search.split('&').forEach(function (item) {
            item = item.split('=');
            keys[item[0]] = item[1];
            /* $('#cssmenu li.has-sub>a').each(function(item){
       if ($(this).html()==$.session.get('open')){
        
        //alert($(this).html());
          var element = $(this).parent('li');
         if (element.hasClass('open')) {
            element.removeClass('open');
            element.find('li').removeClass('open');
            element.find('ul').slideUp();
        }
        else {
           element.addClass('open');
            element.children('ul').slideDown();
            element.siblings('li').children('ul').slideUp();
            element.siblings('li').removeClass('open');
            element.siblings('li').find('li').removeClass('open');
            element.siblings('li').find('ul').slideUp();

        }
       }

        })*/
        });




        $('#cssmenu li.has-sub>a').on('click', function () {
            $.session.set("open", $(this).html());
            //alert($.session.get('open'));
            $(this).removeAttr('href');
            var element = $(this).parent('li');
            if (element.hasClass('open')) {
                element.removeClass('open');
                element.find('li').removeClass('open');
                element.find('ul').slideUp();
            } else {
                element.addClass('open');
                element.children('ul').slideDown();
                element.siblings('li').children('ul').slideUp();
                element.siblings('li').removeClass('open');
                element.siblings('li').find('li').removeClass('open');
                element.siblings('li').find('ul').slideUp();
            }
        });

        $('#cssmenu>ul>li.has-sub>a').append('<span class="holder"></span>');

        (function getColor() {
            var r, g, b;
            var textColor = $('#cssmenu').css('color');
            textColor = textColor.slice(4);
            r = textColor.slice(0, textColor.indexOf(','));
            textColor = textColor.slice(textColor.indexOf(' ') + 1);
            g = textColor.slice(0, textColor.indexOf(','));
            textColor = textColor.slice(textColor.indexOf(' ') + 1);
            b = textColor.slice(0, textColor.indexOf(')'));
            var l = rgbToHsl(r, g, b);
            if (l > 0.7) {
                $('#cssmenu>ul>li>a').css('text-shadow', '0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, .35)');
                $('#cssmenu>ul>li>a>span').css('border-color', 'rgba(0, 0, 0, .35)');
            } else {
                $('#cssmenu>ul>li>a').css('text-shadow', '0 1px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, .35)');
                $('#cssmenu>ul>li>a>span').css('border-color', 'rgba(255, 255, 255, .35)');
            }
        })();

        function rgbToHsl(r, g, b) {
            r /= 255, g /= 255, b /= 255;
            var max = Math.max(r, g, b),
                min = Math.min(r, g, b);
            var h, s, l = (max + min) / 2;

            if (max == min) {
                h = s = 0;
            } else {
                var d = max - min;
                s = l > 0.5 ? d / (2 - max - min) : d / (max + min);
                switch (max) {
                    case r:
                        h = (g - b) / d + (g < b ? 6 : 0);
                        break;
                    case g:
                        h = (b - r) / d + 2;
                        break;
                    case b:
                        h = (r - g) / d + 4;
                        break;
                }
                h /= 6;
            }
            return l;
        }
    });
})(jQuery);
```

```css
div {
    display: block;
}
.general-menu {
    width: 100%;
}
.minilink-menu a {
    font-weight: bold;
    padding: 0.9em 0 0.9em 0.5em;
    display: block;
    font-size: 1.2vw;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-family: Cuprum-Regular, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
    background-color: rgb(133, 135, 139);
    color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
    border-left: 0.1em solid rgb(117, 120, 122);
    border-right: 0.1em solid rgb(117, 120, 122);
    border-top: 0.1em solid rgb(117, 120, 122);
}
.minilink-menu a:hover, .minilink-menu a.active, .minilink-menu a.open {
    color: #eeeeee;
    background: rgb(242, 110, 116);
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(rgb(242, 110, 116), rgb(238, 33, 82));
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(rgb(242, 110, 116), rgb(238, 33, 82));
    background: -o-linear-gradient(rgb(242, 110, 116), rgb(238, 33, 82));
    background: -ms-linear-gradient(rgb(242, 110, 116), rgb(238, 33, 82));
    background: linear-gradient(rgb(242, 110, 116), rgb(238, 33, 82));
}
.minilink-menu a:last-child, .minilink-menu a.last.open, {
    border-bottom: 0.1em solid rgb(117, 120, 122);
}
#cssmenu, #cssmenu ul, #cssmenu ul li, #cssmenu ul li a {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    border: 0;
    list-style: none;
    line-height: 1;
    display: block;
    position: relative;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
#cssmenu {
    width: 100%;
    font-family: Cuprum-Regular, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
    color: #ffffff;
}
#cssmenu ul ul {
    display: none;
}
.align-right {
    float: right;
}
#cssmenu > ul > li > a {
    padding: 1em 2em;
    border-left: 0.1em solid rgb(117, 120, 122);
    border-right: 0.1em solid rgb(117, 120, 122);
    border-top: 0.1em solid rgb(117, 120, 122);
    cursor: pointer;
    z-index: 2;
    font-size: 1vw;
    font-weight: bold;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
    text-shadow: none;
    /* Permalink - use to edit and share this gradient: http://colorzilla.com/gradient-editor/#85878b+0,ffffff+100 */
    background: rgb(133, 135, 139);
    /* Old browsers */
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(left, rgb(133, 135, 139) 0%, rgb(255, 255, 255) 100%);
    /* FF3.6+ */
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, right top, color-stop(0%, rgb(133, 135, 139)), color-stop(100%, rgb(255, 255, 255)));
    /* Chrome,Safari4+ */
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(left, rgb(133, 135, 139) 0%, rgb(255, 255, 255) 100%);
    /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
    background: -o-linear-gradient(left, rgb(133, 135, 139) 0%, rgb(255, 255, 255) 100%);
    /* Opera 11.10+ */
    background: -ms-linear-gradient(left, rgb(133, 135, 139) 0%, rgb(255, 255, 255) 100%);
    /* IE10+ */
    background: linear-gradient(to right, rgb(133, 135, 139) 0%, rgb(255, 255, 255) 100%);
    /* W3C */
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#85878b', endColorstr='#ffffff', GradientType=1);
    /* IE6-9 */
    box-shadow: inset 0 1px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.15);
}
#cssmenu > ul > li > a:hover, #cssmenu > ul > li.active > a {
    color: #eeeeee;
    background: rgb(242, 110, 116);
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(rgb(242, 110, 116), rgb(238, 33, 82));
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(rgb(242, 110, 116), rgb(238, 33, 82));
    background: -o-linear-gradient(rgb(242, 110, 116), rgb(238, 33, 82));
    background: -ms-linear-gradient(rgb(242, 110, 116), rgb(238, 33, 82));
    background: linear-gradient(rgb(242, 110, 116), rgb(238, 33, 82));
}
#cssmenu > ul > li.open > a {
    box-shadow: inset 0 1px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.15), 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
    border-bottom: 1px solid rgb(117, 120, 122);
}
#cssmenu > ul > li:last-child > a, #cssmenu > ul > li.last > a {
    border-bottom: 0.1em solid rgb(117, 120, 122);
}
.holder {
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
}
.holder::after, .holder::before {
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    content:"";
    width: 0.5em;
    height: 0.5em;
    right: 0.7em;
    z-index: 10;
    -webkit-transform: rotate(-135deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(-135deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(-135deg);
    -o-transform: rotate(-135deg);
    transform: rotate(-135deg);
}
.holder::after {
    top: 1.3em;
    border-top: 0.1em solid rgb(133, 135, 139);
    border-left: 0.1em solid rgb(133, 135, 139);
}
#cssmenu > ul > li > a:hover > span::after, #cssmenu > ul > li.active > a > span::after {
    border-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
}
.holder::before {
    top: 1.3em;
    border-top: 0.1em solid;
    border-left: 0.1em solid;
    border-top-color: inherit;
    border-left-color: inherit;
}
#cssmenu ul ul li a {
    cursor: pointer;
    border-left: 0.1em solid rgb(117, 120, 122);
    border-right: 0.1em solid rgb(117, 120, 122);
    border-top: 0.1em solid rgb(117, 120, 122);
    padding: 0.7em 3em;
    z-index: 1;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-weight: normal;
    font-size: 1vw;
    color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
    /* Permalink - use to edit and share this gradient: http://colorzilla.com/gradient-editor/#85878b+0,ffffff+70 */
    background: rgb(133, 135, 139);
    /* Old browsers */
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(left, rgb(133, 135, 139) 0%, rgb(255, 255, 255) 70%);
    /* FF3.6+ */
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, right top, color-stop(0%, rgb(133, 135, 139)), color-stop(70%, rgb(255, 255, 255)));
    /* Chrome,Safari4+ */
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(left, rgb(133, 135, 139) 0%, rgb(255, 255, 255) 70%);
    /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
    background: -o-linear-gradient(left, rgb(133, 135, 139) 0%, rgb(255, 255, 255) 70%);
    /* Opera 11.10+ */
    background: -ms-linear-gradient(left, rgb(133, 135, 139) 0%, rgb(255, 255, 255) 70%);
    /* IE10+ */
    background: linear-gradient(to right, rgb(133, 135, 139) 0%, rgb(255, 255, 255) 70%);
    /* W3C */
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#85878b', endColorstr='#ffffff', GradientType=1);
    /* IE6-9 */
    box-shadow: inset 0 1px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1);
}
#cssmenu ul ul li a:hover {
    color: #eeeeee;
    background: rgb(242, 110, 116);
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(rgb(242, 110, 116), rgb(238, 33, 82));
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(rgb(242, 110, 116), rgb(238, 33, 82));
    background: -o-linear-gradient(rgb(242, 110, 116), rgb(238, 33, 82));
    background: -ms-linear-gradient(rgb(242, 110, 116), rgb(238, 33, 82));
    background: linear-gradient(rgb(242, 110, 116), rgb(238, 33, 82));
}
#cssmenu ul ul li:first-child > a {
    box-shadow: none;
}
#cssmenu ul ul ul li:first-child > a {
    box-shadow: inset 0 1px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1);
}
#cssmenu ul ul ul li a {
    font-weight: normal;
    padding-left: 4em;
    /* Permalink - use to edit and share this gradient: http://colorzilla.com/gradient-editor/#85878b+0,ffffff+45 */
    background: rgb(133, 135, 139);
    /* Old browsers */
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(left, rgb(133, 135, 139) 0%, rgb(255, 255, 255) 45%);
    /* FF3.6+ */
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, right top, color-stop(0%, rgb(133, 135, 139)), color-stop(45%, rgb(255, 255, 255)));
    /* Chrome,Safari4+ */
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(left, rgb(133, 135, 139) 0%, rgb(255, 255, 255) 45%);
    /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
    background: -o-linear-gradient(left, rgb(133, 135, 139) 0%, rgb(255, 255, 255) 45%);
    /* Opera 11.10+ */
    background: -ms-linear-gradient(left, rgb(133, 135, 139) 0%, rgb(255, 255, 255) 45%);
    /* IE10+ */
    background: linear-gradient(to right, rgb(133, 135, 139) 0%, rgb(255, 255, 255) 45%);
    /* W3C */
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#85878b', endColorstr='#ffffff', GradientType=1);
    /* IE6-9 */
}
#cssmenu ul ul ul li a.active, #cssmenu ul ul ul li a:hover {
    color: #eeeeee;
    background: rgb(242, 110, 116);
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(rgb(242, 110, 116), rgb(238, 33, 82));
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(rgb(242, 110, 116), rgb(238, 33, 82));
    background: -o-linear-gradient(rgb(242, 110, 116), rgb(238, 33, 82));
    background: -ms-linear-gradient(rgb(242, 110, 116), rgb(238, 33, 82));
    background: linear-gradient(rgb(242, 110, 116), rgb(238, 33, 82));
}
#cssmenu > ul > li > ul > li.active:last > a {
    color: #eeeeee;
    background: rgb(242, 110, 116);
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(rgb(242, 110, 116), rgb(238, 33, 82));
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(rgb(242, 110, 116), rgb(238, 33, 82));
    background: -o-linear-gradient(rgb(242, 110, 116), rgb(238, 33, 82));
    background: -ms-linear-gradient(rgb(242, 110, 116), rgb(238, 33, 82));
    background: linear-gradient(rgb(242, 110, 116), rgb(238, 33, 82));
}
#cssmenu > ul > li > ul > li:last-child > a, #cssmenu > ul > li > ul > li.last > a {
    border-bottom: 0;
}
#cssmenu > ul > li > ul > li.open:last-child > a {
    border-bottom: 0.1em solid rgb(117, 120, 122);
}
#cssmenu > ul > li > ul > li.open:last-child > ul > li:last-child > a {
    border-bottom: 0;
}
#cssmenu ul ul li.has-sub > a::after {
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    content:"";
    width: 0.5em;
    height: 0.5em;
    right: 0.7em;
    z-index: 10;
    top: 0.9em;
    border-top: 0.2em solid rgb(133, 135, 139);
    border-left: 0.2em solid rgb(133, 135, 139);
    -webkit-transform: rotate(-135deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(-135deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(-135deg);
    -o-transform: rotate(-135deg);
    transform: rotate(-135deg);
}
#cssmenu ul ul li.active > a::after, #cssmenu ul ul li > a:hover::after {
    border-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="general-menu">
    <div class="minilink-menu"> <a href="index.php" class="buttom active">Головна</a>
 <a href="page/about-the-company.php" class="buttom">Про компанію</a>
 <a href="page/services.php" class="buttom">Послуги</a>

        <div id='cssmenu'>
            <ul>
                <li class='has-sub'><a href='#'><span>Брокерська діяльність</span></a>

                    <ul>
                        <li class='has-sub'><a href='#'><span>Фондовий ринок</span></a>

                            <ul>
                                <li><a href='page/how-to-connect.php?parametr=yak_pidkluchitis'><span>Як підключитись</span></a>

                                </li>
                                <li><a href='page/fares.php'><span>Тарифи</span></a>

                                </li>
                                <li class='last'><a href='page/samples-of-contracts.php'><span>Зразки договорів</span></a>

                                </li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                        <li class='has-sub'><a href='#'><span>Строковий ринок</span></a>

                            <ul>
                                <li><a href='page/how-to-connect.php'><span>Як підключитись</span></a>

                                </li>
                                <li><a href='page/fares.php'><span>Тарифи </span></a>

                                </li>
                                <li class='last'><a href='page/samples-of-contracts.php'><span>Зразки </span></a>

                                </li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li class='has-sub'><a href='#'><span>Інвестиційно-банківське обслуговування</span></a>

                    <ul>
                        <li><a href='page/mergers-and-acquisitions.php'><span>Злиття і поглинання  підприємств</span></a>

                        </li>
                        <li class='last'><a href='page/issue-and-placement-of-securities.php'><span>Випуск та розміщення цінних паперів</span></a>

                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li class='has-sub last'><a href='#'><span>Діяльність Депозитарної Установи</span></a>

                    <ul>
                        <li class='has-sub'><a href='#'><span>Депозитарні послуги</span></a>

                            <ul>
                                <li><a href='page/documents-for-depositors.php'><span>Пакети документів для депонентів</span></a>

                                </li>
                                <li><a href='page/forms-orders.php'><span>Форми розпоряджень</span></a>

                                </li>
                                <li><a href='page/services-for-Issuers.php'><span>Послуги для Емітентів</span></a>

                                </li>
                                <li><a href='page/services-for-ici.php'><span>Послуги для ІСІ</span></a>

                                </li>
                                <li class='last'><a href='page/statement-of-account-of-the-depositor.php'><span>Надання виписки про стан рахунку Депонента</span></a>

                                </li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                        <li class='has-sub'><a href='#'><span>Корпоративне управління</span></a>

                            <ul>
                                <li><a href='page/organization-and-conduct-of-the-general-meetingsof-shareholders.php'><span>Організація та про ведення Загальних зборів акціонерів</span></a>

                                </li>
                                <li><a href='page/disclosure-in-issuers-stock-market.php'><span>Розкриття інформації на фондовому ринку Емітентами</span></a>

                                </li>
                                <li><a href='page/reduction-of-blood-pressure-in-accordance-with-the-law-of-ukraine.php'><span>Приведення діяльності АТ у відповідність з Законом України «Про акціонерні товариства» </span></a>

                                </li>
                                <li class='last'><a href='page/interaction-with-the-central-depositary.php'><span>Взаємодія з ЦД </span></a>

                                </li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div> <a href="page/the-asset-management-company.php" class="buttom">Компанія з управління активами</a>
 <a href="page/documents.php" class="buttom">Документи</a>
 <a href="page/contacts.php" class="buttom">Контакти</a>

    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Каким образом вы пытались обнаружить ошибку?

Comment: [Вот скрин.](http://i072.radikal.ru/1508/78/94a545d144a1.png)
Дело в том, что при переходе на индекс-2, меню всё равно свернуто, а должно быть развернутым.

Answer (score 1):

При загрузке новой страницы нужно смотреть элемент на соответствие разделу *(это может html элемент на странице, можно просто вывести переменную с бэка, можно ориентироваться по урлу и др.)* и js'oм разворачивать нужный блок меню. А если бы  сайт был SPA - то еще проще было бы.